# A function that gets two variables and their order doesn't matter

Tags: c#, function, variables

Sorry that I couldn't explain better in the question header. I'll try to define my question better here.

That's what I am doing - in my game, there is an option to use items on one another. For each pair of items, the game performs an action.

Currently, there are two variables that game uses for this: "ItemUsed" and "ItemUsedOn". First, the game chooses first item - its id goes to "ItemUsed", then he chooses second item, it's id goes to "ItemUsedOn". Then, there is a void that defines a specific action.

A short example of code:

```
if (ItemUsed == "itm_cable")
{
    if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_towel")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "To achieve what?";
    else if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_wet_towel")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "No, water will damage it";
    else if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_glass")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "I don't need to cut the cable";
}

if (ItemUsed == "itm_book_electronics")
{
    if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_towel")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "Why?";
    if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_wet_towel")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "No, water will damage the book";
    else if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_soap")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "Wrong plan";
    else if (ItemUsedOn == "itm_hair")
        SubMain.ItemsMergedText = "It won't help";
}
```

And there are many such pairs.
However, there is a problem with this approach. When two items are combined, their order doesn't matter, for example "itm_toolbox" can be "ItemUsed" and "itm_cable" can be "ItemUsedOn", but also can be the other way around, the result will be the same. How can this be achieved?

I did try using this in every "larger" if:

```
else
    CombineItems(ItemUsedOn, "itm_book_edda");
```

But this doesn't always work, and I couldn't find why.

So, what I am looking for is function that gets 2 variables:

```
void CombineItems(string Item1, string Item2)
```

And then give same result in those cases:

```
if (Item1="Tomato")&&(Item2="Cucumber")
    Item3="Salad"

if (Item1="Cucumber")&&(Item2="Tomato")
    Item3="Salad"
```

My question: is there an easier way for this, without using so many "if's"?

Thank you in advance,
Evgenie

Comment: Using switch statements will make it more readable...

Comment: I would consider restructuring your code, this looks like it will be a pain to maintain. If each object were a class, which inherits from an interface exposing a 'Combine' method, you can pass the ItemUsed into the ItemUsedOn.

Comment: Alas, I am way too deep into coding to make major changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend that you create yourself an eg `UnorderedPair` type, which overrides the behaviour of `.Equals` and/or `==`, such that:

```
new UnorderedPair("Tomato", "Cumcumber") == new UnorderedPair("Cucumber", "Tomato");
```

Then you can reduce all of your `if` statements down to a simple dictionary:

```
combinedItems = new Dictionary<UnderedPair, string>
{
    [new UnorderedPair("Tomato", "Cumcumber")] = "Salad",
    [new UnorderedPair("Bread", "Filling")] = "Sandwich",
    ...
};
```

and your code for determining the text can then just be:

```
SubMain.ItemsMergedText = combinedItems[new UnorderedPair(ItemUsed, ItemUsedOn)];
```

Comment: Nice. But what if there are more than two ingredients? Some foods have more, even some salads have more than 2 ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, The answer to that would surely depend on how many more. The unordered set approach could be applied to three items, maybe four or more. But it would quickly become unwieldy and so at some point the developer would be better off switching to a different solution, eg generating a statistically unique hash of sorted ingredients as the key.

Comment: This looks like the most fitting answer, I'll try that from home. Replying to Tim Schmelter - items can only be combined by pairs.

Comment: Sorry for more questions - if the result will be void, and not string, this approach will still work, right?

Comment: @EvgenieT, I'm unclear on what you mean by "the result will be void". Do you mean you want to call a void method, based on  `ItemUsed` and `ItemUsedOn`? If so, then change the value part of the dictionary from `string` to `Action` and invoke the method supplied. Let me know if that is what you mean and I'll update the answer to explain this more.

Comment: Yes, each items combination start a void() method, usually it has a string to show, voice file to play and sometimes other actions like adding or removing an item (I already have code for this).

Comment: I had problems using the code you suggested. I created a class UnorderedPair that gets two string, but I still can't use the following line: ***new UnorderedPair("itm_towel", "itm_wet_towel") == new UnorderedPair("itm_wet_towel" , "itm_towel");*** Don't I need to create some kind of variable for it first?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `params`(to treat them as array) and LINQ. Store the salad-items in an array too:

```
private string[] SaladItems = new string[] { "Tomato", "Cucumber" };

string CombineItems(params string[] Items)
{
    bool isSalad = SaladItems.Length == Items.Length && !SaladItems.Except(Items).Any();
    if (isSalad) return "Salad";
    // other types ...

    return null; // no match, exception?
}
```

Side-Note: if you want to accept "tomato"(so ignore the case) use:

```
!SaladItems.Except(Items, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Any()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make this endless list of comparisons a lot smaller if you structure the logic into separate parts.

First, I would create a list or so to keep the items and their result:

```
var items = new[] { new { Item1 = "tomato", Item2 = "Cucumber", Result = "Salad" }
                  , new { Item1 = "tomato2", Item2 = "Cucumber2", Result = "Salad2" }
                  };
```

Then find the matching item:

```
var match = items.FirstOrDefault
                (itm => (itm.Item1 == Item1 && itm.Item2 == Item2)
                        || (itm.Item1 == Item2 && itm.Item2 == Item1)
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches that can keep down the amount of duplication throughout the code:

- Sort the items so they're alphabetical order:

  ```
  if(Item1 > Item2) {
    var tmp = Item2;
    Item2 = Item1;
    Item1 = tmp;
  }
  ```

  now all of your remaining code can assume that `Item1` values will always be earlier alphabetically than `Item2`, so you'd only write:

  ```
   if (Item1="Cucumber")&&(Item2="Tomato")
       Item3="Salad"
  ```
- Or, you can, after exhausting all of your options (again, written only once), call your method recursively with the parameters swapped:

  ```
  void TakeAction(Item1, Item2) {
       .
       .
       .
       /* No matches */
       else {
           TakeAction(Item2,Item1);
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: I considered doing something like this, but looking for better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items= new HashSet<string>();
items.Add("tomato");
items.Add("Cucumber");

if(items.Contains("tomato") && items.Contains("Cucumber")) //Order does **NOT** matter
     Item3="Salad";
```